# swift how to return function with same argument usage of default value and label

Tags: swift, function, types

I want to return a function and invoke it as bb in the code

```
func bb(a: Int, b: String = "b") {
  print(a, b)
}

typealias FnOfBb = (Int, String) -> Void

func cc() -> FnOfBb {
  return bb
}

bb(a: 1) // is ok

cc()(a: 1) // desired, but show Error: Extraneous argument label 'a:' in call  and  Missing argument for parameter #2 in call

cc()(1, "str") // is ok, but different of bb
```

aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000 aaa 000

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that closures can't have externally named parameters, which is why your `cc()(a: 1)` gives you a that error.

If keeping the externally named parameter is important, you'll have do with something that is callable like a function but isn't a function:

```swift
@dynamicCallable struct Callable
{
    let closure: (Int, String) -> Void
    func dynamicallyCall(withKeywordArguments args: KeyValuePairs<String, Int>)
    {
        let a = Int(args.first?.value ?? 0)
        let b = args.count > 1 ? String(args[1].value) : "b"
        closure(a, b)
    }
}

func bb(a: Int, b: String = "b") {
  print(a, b)
}

func cc() -> Callable {
    return Callable(closure: bb)
}

cc()(a: 1)
```

prints

```
1 b
```

It's probably not perfectly what you're looking for.  For example, given the same definitions, it will accept this:

```swift
cc()(foo: 5) // accepts different external name
```

prints

```
5 b
```

You can check for this in `Callable`, but it's a run-time thing:

```swift
@dynamicCallable struct Callable
{
    let closure: (Int, String) -> Void
    func dynamicallyCall(withKeywordArguments args: KeyValuePairs<String, Int>)
    {
        precondition(args.count > 0 && args.first!.key == "a")
        let a = Int(args.first?.value ?? 0)
        let b = args.count > 1 ? String(args[1].value) : "b"
        closure(a, b)
    }
}
```

Now this will compile but will `fatalError` at runtime:

```swift
cc()(foo: 5) // Precondition fails here
```

As for default values... as far as I know there isn't a way to infer them from the function that's being assigned, so I don't think there is a solution for that.